# Break into chrome debugger when console.assert fails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How can I cause a break when `console.assert()` fails (other than replacing assert function with my own and setting breakpoint there) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you first fire up the Chrome Developer Tool

Click on the pause icon that says on mouseover 
`"Do not pause on exceptions. Click to pause on all exceptions"` at the very bottom bar of the Chrome Developer Tool near the left side. If you can not find that icon, press the `Sources` tab within the Chrome Developer Tool.

That icon should turn blue. If it doesn't turn blue the first time, click on it a second time. Then, it will pause even on `console.assert(false);`

Comment: Great suggestion! But it's better if the icon is purple (clicked twice) which means it'll break only at uncaught exceptions. I'm using jQuery and there are so many caught exceptions that if the icon is blue (clicked once) it'll be breaking almost every second which is annoying

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to break automatically on failed `assert()`s, at least in Chrome/Safari.

But I think replacing with your own is actually almost as good:

```
var nativeAssert = console.assert;
function assertWrapper(expr) {
    nativeAssert.apply(this, arguments);
    if (!expr) {
        "";
    }
}
console.assert = assertWrapper;
```

Then you can just place a breakpoint on the `""` line to catch all failures, while still getting the standard console output you expect.